# Smoke detector interfacing with FS32K146HAT0MLLT

Tags: microcontroller, analog, sensor, adc, filter

I am using [MQ-2](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-mq2-gas-sensor-with-arduino) smoke detector in my design.The sensor is working at **5V** supply.This sensor has both analog and digital outputs.

I am using analog output in my design.The microcontroller used is [FS32K146HAT0MLLT](https://www.nxp.com/part/FS32K146HAT0MLLT#/) from NXP.The controller is also working at 5V.

The analog output varies from 0V to 5V so I did not use any voltage scaling circuit between sensor and microcontroller.

A LPF of cut off frequency 1.6Khz(arbitrarily chosen) is kept at the output of sensor.

May I know this circuit is fine or do I need to take care any other things.

[image]

In the datasheet I can see a current limit resistor(RL).Is that necessary.
How do I design that resistor.

[image]